# Display a limited number of labels only on X-Axis of Line Chart using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

1) How to display only first, middle and last OR only first and last labels(Dates) on X-Axis of Line chart using chart.js?

2) Also, if possible I want to display only those specific number of vertical gridlines.

Code:

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: reportDate,
        datasets:[{
            label: 'ABC',
            data: abcArray,
            backgroundColor:"white",
            borderColor: "darkblue",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0,
            radius: 5
        },{
            label: 'DEF',
            data: defArray,
            backgroundColor:"white",
            borderColor: "magenta",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0,
            radius: 5
        },{
            label: 'XYZ',
            data: xyzArray,
            backgroundColor:"white",
            borderColor: "lightgreen",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0,
            radius: 5
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        scales:{
            xAxes:[{
                ticks:{
                    display: true
                }
            }],
            yAxes:[{
                gridLines:{
                    display: false
                }
            }]
        },
        tooltips:{
            mode:'index'
        }
    }
});
```

[Line Chart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDWQT.png)

Comment: Line number 4 - `labels: reportDate` - In this reportDate is an array of dates which will be later in format of mm/dd/yyyy, thus I need to display less number of dates so the UI looks cleaner.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This worked perfectly.

```
xAxes:[{
    ticks:{
        display: true,
        autoSkip: true,
        maxTicksLimit: 4
    }
}]
```

Comment: Beautiful in its simplicity.

Comment: Is there any option along with maxTicks so as to also show the last label value ?

Comment: FYI - In Chartsjs v3, `xAxes` has been renamed to `x`.  @ShubhamSinghvi, comments aren't the proper place to ask new questions.  Instead, you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

**Above Char.js Version 4.21**

xAxes was changed to x and array format was changed to object format

Example:

```
  scales: {
    x: {
      ticks: {
        display: true,
        autoSkip: true,
        maxTicksLimit: 15,
      },
    },
  },
```

Source: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#common-tick-options-to-all-cartesian-axes